# How do I edit a custom text field on multiple documents all at once?

Tags: column

I have a custom text field that I use for all of my library documents (poor man's tagging).  I wish to modify a group in a batch.  How do insert a string directly into the text field for all the chosen files?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm not quite sure that I understand exactly but why don't you go into datasheet view for the document library, change the option and simply drag the value down like you would in Excel and this will quickly update the value of the chosen items.

I could be misunderstanding the question though....

Comment: That sounds like a good idea to replace the values with one (though I can't get the drag to work like it does in Excel), but what I'm looking for is to insert a string into the existing field without changing the rest of the field.  I imagine I'll have to work up some code to handle this.

Comment: The drag to fill ought to work in IE. Do you mean that you want to change *part* of the contents of a column value?  You'll probably need to turn to code for that.